# A question about reduced C*-algebra of discrete group

Tags: algebraic-topology, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

There is a quotation below:

Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete group and $\Lambda\subset \Gamma$ be a subgroup. The right cosets give a direct sum decomposition
$$l^{2}(\Gamma)\cong\bigoplus l^{2}(\Lambda g)$$
 and hence the left regular representation of $\Gamma$, when restricted to $\Lambda$, is a multiple of the left regular representation of $\Lambda$ (multiplicity equals the number of cosets). This implies

**Proposition 2.5.9.** If $\Lambda\subset\Gamma$ is a subgroup, then $C^{*}_{\lambda}(\Lambda)\subset C^{*}_{\lambda}(\Gamma)$ canonicallly. (The $C^{*}_{\lambda}(.)$ denotes the *reduced* C*-algebra of (.)).

**I have three question about this quotation:**

1. How to verify the direct sum decomposition $l^{2}(\Gamma)\cong\bigoplus l^{2}(\Lambda g)$ ?
2. How to comprehend that the left regular representation of $\Gamma$ is a multiple of the left regular representation of $\Lambda$?
3. How to get the Proposition 2.5.9.from the analysis?

Recall The *reduced group* C*-algebra of $\Gamma$, denoted $C_{\lambda}^{*}(\Gamma)$, is the completion of $\mathbb{C}(\Gamma)$ with respect to the norm $$||x||_{r}=||\lambda(x)||_{\mathbb{B}(l^{2}(\Gamma))}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. They are just saying that if $A=\bigcup_nA_n$, then $\ell^2(A)\simeq\bigoplus \ell^2(A_n)$. The direct sum has to be understood as a direct sum of Hilbert spaces, i.e. an $\ell^2$-sum.
2. The left regular representation of $\Lambda$ leaves each direct summand invariant. So we can think of it acting that way on $\ell^2(\Gamma)$ (as a block-diagonal operator).
3. By 1 and 2 one gets how to see $\lambda_\Lambda$ as $\lambda_\Gamma|_\Lambda$. So $C^*_\lambda(\Lambda)$ is generated by a subalgebra of $C^*_\lambda(\Gamma)$.

Comment: Do you mean, in answer 2, if $\lambda$ is the left regular representation of $\Lambda$, then, from the decomposition, we have that $\phi(s)=\lambda(s)\oplus \lambda(s)\oplus...$ ,for $s\in \Lambda$, is a restrict of a left regular representation of $\Gamma$?

Comment: Yes. ${\ \ \ \ }$